# Not able to track users that has closed the tab

Tags: jquery

I was able to create a site where I was able to count how many people scrolled to a section of the page and the number of people gets put into a .txt file. I've been looking but I don't seem to be able to figure out how to track how many people has left the site either by closing the page or leaving it.
Can someone help me with this, because I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

Here is the code that I have

```
    var hasScrolled = "blank";
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var y_scroll_pos = window.pageYOffset;
    if(isIE()<9 && isIE() != false){
        var y_scroll_pos = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    }
    if(y_scroll_pos > 200){
        $(".header-inner").addClass("sticky");
        $(".mazda-logo-left").addClass("sticky");
    }else{
        $(".header-inner").removeClass("sticky");
        $(".mazda-logo-left").removeClass("sticky");
    }

    //console.log("hasScrolled" +hasScrolled)
    $(".scrollpos").each(function(index, element) {
        //$("body").append("#"+$(this).parent().attr("id"))
        var scroll_pos_test = $("#"+$(this).parent().attr("id")).offset().top;

        if(y_scroll_pos >= scroll_pos_test && y_scroll_pos < Number(scroll_pos_test)+$(this).parent().innerHeight()) {
            if(hasScrolled != $(this).parent().attr("id")){

                hasScrolled = $(this).parent().attr("id");

                tracker($.trim(hasScrolled));

                if ( hasScrolled == 'the-idea' ) {
                    //$(".wrapper").css("background","red")
                    $.getJSON('update_count.php?section=idea');
                }
                if ( hasScrolled == 'the-tech' ) {
                     //$(".wrapper").css("background","blue")
                    $.getJSON('update_count.php?section=tech');
                }
                if (  hasScrolled == 'the-result'  ) {
                     //$(".wrapper").css("background","yellow")
                    $.getJSON('update_count.php?section=result');
                }

            }
        }
    });


});

    $(".nav a").click(function(){
        $(".nav a").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        tracker($.trim($(this).attr("data-id")));
        var dataCo = $(this).attr("data-id");
        if ( dataCo == 'the-idea' ) {
            $.getJSON('update_count.php?section=idea');
        }
        if ( dataCo == 'the-tech' ) {
            $.getJSON('update_count.php?section=tech');
        }
        if (  dataCo == 'the-result'  ) {
            $.getJSON('update_count.php?section=result');
        }

    });
```

I have tried

```
$( window ).unload(function() {
   alert( "Bye now!" );
});
```

in various places, like in the  section and just before the  tag. As well as in my main.js

Comment: You can't do that. Running a AJAX request is asynchronous and the browser will most likely abort it, if you start it in an unload event, because that is what the browser is now doing - unloading the page. Keep in mind it's not your browser, there is no reliable way to know if a user closes/exits a page or closes his browser.

Comment: Then can you suggest anything I could do that would do the same thing or doesn't anything like that exist?